# Q8300 Core-2 Quad vs X3360 Xeon

Tags: windows-server-2008, central-processing-unit, multi-core

I'm looking at [this](http://www.abmx.com/1u-short-depth-server) ABMX server, and trying to decide on the CPU.  I'm purchasing 2 servers, to be used as dedicated web and DB servers for a web site that has low traffic now but could ramp up quickly.

Just trying to decide if it is worth about $200 more (per server) for the Xeon vs the core-2.  Passmark rates them at 3567 and 4153, which didn't seem that different.  I'm not planning at this point to need virtualization.  I did hear rumors that Xeon stands up better in a 24/7 server environment, but heard others say there wasn't that much difference.

Planning to run Windows Server 2008, likely the R2 release, with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has 3 times more L2 cache, not to mention more raw processing power, so if you think you'll need a lot of processing power get the X3360.

The X3360 is the equivalent of the Q9550. One has a Xeon label, the other does not, but they are both identical.

Why are you investing in hardware on a hunch? Or is it wishful thinking? There is quite a lot of hassle when colocating, such as buying extra replacement parts and either driving down there to replace a failed drive in your RAID (assuming you are using RAID, which you should) or paying at least 60$/hour to have someone replace it for you.

You can get quite some decent deals on renting high-end servers if you know the right people, and it will leave you with no responsibility when it comes to failed hardware, and no servers that you need to sell in case your website doesn't pick up momentum fast.

Comment: I looked at renting (for example hosting.com).  However, it looked like you only get a fraction of 1 CPU and about 1GB of RAM.  Then, when you need more you easily hit $200+ per month.  I can get an 8th cabinet for $200/m at cololocker, and buy the servers for 3k.  I think there's a good chance traffic could pick up quickly and would like to be prepared and have it be responsive.  Btw I was thinking to start with RAID1 mirroring, 2 1TB WD HDD.

Comment: You're paying 500$/mo. for the two servers (6k$/12) as well as 200$ for the colo, so it's now 700$ per mo. with 5mbps bandwidth, which might need to be increased to the 350$ per mo. plan so you can have 20mbps, since you'll go over 5 mbps really fast. On top of these you'll also need a switch.

From one of my hosts, 478east I asked for a custom quote, and it seems you could get a server with an i7 860(x3460), 16GB of RAM and 4 146GB SAS drives in RAID-10 with 5TB of bandwidth for 360$. If you only ask the expensive hosts, expect expensive prices :). This server is obviously not fully managed.

Comment: I meant 3k for 2 servers (1.5k ea), still seems like a better deal to purchase and rent, rather than spend the same amount on renting and own no servers after 12m.

Comment: If you think you're better off owning then go for it, but renting allows you to easily expand from month to month to a different server and leaves you with less responsibilities.